# Postgresql - how to run a query on multiple tables with same schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a postgres database that has several tables (a few hundreds). A **subset** *Foo* of the tables in the database have the same schema.

Ideally, I would like to create a stored procedure which can run a query against a single table, or against all tables in subset *Foo*.

**Pseudocode:**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_a (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(32), weight double, age INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE tbl_b (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(32), weight double, age INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE tbl_c (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(32), weight double, age INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE tbl_d (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(32), weight double, age INTEGER);

CREATE TYPE person_info AS (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(32), weight double, age INTEGER);

CREATE FUNCTION generic_func(ARRAY one_or_more_table_names)
    RETURNS person_info 
    -- Run query on table or all specified tables
    AS $$  $$
    LANGUAGE SQL;
```

How could I implement this requirement in Postgresql 9.x ?

Comment: Unrelated, but: "Postgres 9.x" covers **7** different major version (with two of them no longer supported). You need to be more specific with the Postgres version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should have a look at [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html) in PostgreSQL, they allow exactly what you speak about.

For example, you could create a table parent_tbl:

```
CREATE TABLE parent_tbl (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(32), weight numeric, age INTEGER);
```

Then link your tables to this parent table:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_a INHERIT parent_tbl;
ALTER TABLE tbl_b INHERIT parent_tbl;
ALTER TABLE tbl_c INHERIT parent_tbl;
ALTER TABLE tbl_d INHERIT parent_tbl;
```

Then a SELECT query over parent_tbl will query all of tbl_x tables, while a query on tbl_x will query only this particular table.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_a VALUES (1, 'coucou', 42, 42);

SELECT * FROM tbl_a;
 id |  name  | weight | age 
----+--------+--------+-----
  1 | coucou |     42 |  42
(1 row)

SELECT * FROM parent_tbl;
 id |  name  | weight | age 
----+--------+--------+-----
  1 | coucou |     42 |  42
(1 row)

SELECT * FROM tbl_b;
 id |  name  | weight | age 
----+--------+--------+-----
(0 rows)
```

It is also possible to filter data from given children tables. For example, if you are interested in data coming from tables tbl_a and tbl_b, you can do

```
select id, name, weight, age
from parent_tbl
left join pg_class on oid = parent_tbl.tableoid
where relname in ('tbl_a', 'tbl_b');
```

EDIT : I put numeric for weight instead of double as this type is not supported on my server.

Comment: +1 Neat solution for the use case where I need to run queries on all the tables, but in the instances where I need to run on a specific table, I need to repeat the same code for some 300+ tables! I have since found out that passing the name of a table to a query is bad form. Is there a way where I could perhaps introduce another table and use JOINS to restrict the query run on the parent table, to only the data in say, table_a?

Comment: Sure! You can use the tableoid column. I'll update my answer, just leave me 5 minutes

Comment: Thanks!, I bow humbly before your Postgresqlfu ! ;)

Answer (score 6):

To create select query dynamically using items(table name) in an array you can use following select statement

```
SELECT string_agg(q, ' union all ')
FROM  (
    SELECT 'select * from ' || unnest(array ['tble_a','tble_b']) AS q
    ) t
```

Result:

```
string_agg                                          
--------------------------------------------------- 
select * from tble_a union all select * from tble_b
```

You can create the function that returns table with columns

```
 id INTEGER
,name VARCHAR(32)
,weight numeric
,age INTEGER
```

P.S: I am avoiding `TYPE person_info`

function:

```
CREATE
    OR REPLACE FUNCTION generic_func (tbl varchar [])
RETURNS TABLE (         -- To store the output
        id INTEGER
        ,name VARCHAR(32)
        ,weight numeric
        ,age INTEGER
        ) AS $BODY$

DECLARE qry text;

BEGIN
    SELECT string_agg(q, ' union all ')  --To create select query dynamically
    INTO qry
    FROM (
        SELECT 'select * from ' || unnest(tbl) AS q
        ) t;

    RAISE NOTICE 'qry %',qry; --optional

    RETURN query --Executes the query to the defined table

    EXECUTE qry;
END;$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Usage:

```
select * from generic_func(array['tbl_a','tbl_b','tbl_c','tbl_d'])
```

Result:

```
id name weight age 
-- ---- ------ --- 
2  ABC  11     112 
2  CBC  11     112 
2  BBC  11     112 
2  DBC  11     112
```

and

`select * from generic_func(array['tbl_a'])`

```
Result:
id name weight age 
-- ---- ------ --- 
2  ABC  11     112
```

Comment: +1 I like this as it allows me to specify the name of the table. However, I have since found that this is considered an Anti-Pattern (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter). I'm therefore currently, leaning more in favour of Fabian's answer - which rather elegantly, satisfies the requirement of "multi-table queries" - but seems unwieldy (requiring each table to have it's own "version" of a query, where the tablename is hardcoded in the query/SP.